# SQL Server - Restricting datatypes to take inputs of specified size

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I declare a data type in sqlserver Database as Varchar(20). It means it can allow input of length equal to or less than 20 characters.

However my requirement is such that I need Varchar(20) to take exactly the defined length of input i.e it should not accept the input if its length is not exactly 20.

Can we do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add a check constraint to the column, to validate that the length of its value is 20. Furthermore, you should consider using the CHAR(20) datatype instead of VARCHAR(20).

To add a check constraint to column "MyColumn" of table "MyTable", do this:

```
ALTER 
TABLE MyTable ADD CHECK (LEN(MyColumn)=20)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to have the strings padded to 20 characters you could use a char(20) rather than varchar(20) which will force 20 characters.

If you don't want padding the best place to validate it would be in the application and then have a backup check in the insert logic that checks the length is 20 e.g. `len(@MyString) = 20;` and not do the insert and return an message back to the application if it fails.

If you are inserting using a direct insert you could put a constraint on the column requiring the length to be 20; which would cause an error on insert.

e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[YOUR_TABLE]
ADD CONSTRAINT [ColLengthConstraint] CHECK (DATALENGTH([your_column]) = 20)
```